# module exports object searching and getting items node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object, discord

I have this file called `file.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    emojis
}
const emojis = {
    "a": "",
    "b": "", 
    "c": "", 
    "d": "",
    "e": "", 
    "f": "", 
    "g": "", 
    "h": "",
    "i": "", 
    "j": "", 
    "k": "", 
    "l": "",
    "m": "", 
    "n": "", 
    "o": "", 
    "p": "",
    "q": "", 
    "r": "", 
    "s": "", 
    "t": "",
    "u": "", 
    "v": "", 
    "w": "", 
    "x": "",
    "y": "", 
    "z": "", 
}
```

I imported it  with `const emojis = require("../file.js")`

Lets say I have a char `const char = "p"`

How can I do those two things:

1. Test if char is equal to and of those "keys" or indexes, so the left side.
2. Second if yes, I want to get the appropriate value, so the right side.

Comment: 1- `if(char in Object.keys(emojis))` 2- `emojis[char]`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `const { emojis } = require ....` since the thing being exported is `{ emojis: { ... } }` ?

Comment: `if(emojis[char]) { const emodji = emojis[char] }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const { emojis } = require("../file.js")
const char = "p";

if(char in emojis){
 let rightvalue = emojis[char];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have imported emojis and you have a variable called char.
1.Since emojis is an object and you want to see if char is equal to any key in the emojis object you can use `Object.keys(emojis)` and it returns an array so you can iterate over it using a `forEach` loop or a for loop and compare each value in the array returned by `Object.keys` to your variable char and if it's equal to any save to a variable lets call it value for example
here is how ===

```
const char = "p"
let value;
 Object.keys(emojis).forEach(x=>{
   if(x===char){
    value=x;
   }
 })
```

2. You can access the value to the right side by doing this `emojis[value]`

You can also use a for..in loop
i.e

```
for(x in emojis){
 if(x === char){
   value = x;
   // x will the the name a property if you wish to access the value you'll
    //have to do this emojis[x] or outside the loop emojis[value]
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you export an object which is essentially a map, you can simply look up the characters since they refer to the keys of the object. Consider this simple example:

```js
const emojis = {
    "a": "",
    "b": "", 
    "c": "", 
    "d": ""
};

function findKey(key, map) {
  return map[key];
}

const keys = ["c", "p"];

keys.forEach(key => {
  const mappedValue = findKey(key, emojis);
  if(mappedValue) {
    console.log(`found value '${mappedValue}' for key '${key}'`);
  }else {
    console.log(`did not find value for key '${key}'`);
  }
});
```